# SP2010: Use Workflow to move library item into folder

Tags: 2010, workflow, document, folder, library

I need my workflow to move library documents into a folder in the same document library. I can copy items, then delete the original item. I'm not seeing how to specify a folder or sub-folder, just the list itself. I'm just not seeing it (therefor it is probably right in front of my nose!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use SharePoint 2010 designer, you can try to use this [activity](http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Copy%20List%20Item%20Extended%20Activity&referringTitle=Home).

Comment: While this looks like an EXCELLENT solution, I'm not sure how to implement. I'm assuming I need to have access to the Admin side of the SP farm? I have never tried to add anything like this ... I have asked our administrators for assistance, but have not gotten word back yet. I have looked at these two sites for assistance: [Creating Custon Workflow Activity](http://blog.voltje.be/2010/12/17/creating-custom-workflow-activities-for-sharepoint-2010/) and [Custom Activity Workflow](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18415/Custom-Activity-Workflow-for-implementing-Item-Lev)

Comment: @Paulster2, you need to install this activity and create workflow in SharePoint designer.For example you can look at this [post](http://plexhosted.com/billing/knowledgebase/226/How-to-create-a-simple-approval-workflow-in-SharePoint-Designer.html)

Comment: I guess my follow-up question was not clear. I know how to create workflows ... I don't know how to install the activity. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: go to [downloads](http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/releases/view/10103). In the zip package you will find installation guide.

Comment: Let's assume I'm a total numb-skull ... I did read the the installation guide, but as usual, it assumes I've done installations of extraneous items into SP in the past. I do not have access to the farm. Our SP Designer is delivered through XenApp and the Admins will not (or are deign to) install ANYTHING outside of the software. I'm at a loss of how to make this happen. I do appreciate the help. Please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: this solution requires deployment to the farm. if you develop own solution you need to deploy it too. I do not have any proposal for you now (

Comment: Thanks for all your help Alex ... marked your response as the answer, as I'm sure it would do exactly what I would need it to do.

Comment: Down voted as this answer is just a link to a web page. It is likely that this page will vanish one day, as codeplex is now dead, and has been archived. Please add the content to your answer so it remains useful after codeplex has been switched off.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old thread, but after spending a good while looking about I found an OOTB SharePoint Designer 2010 solution for this problem.

To move a document to a different folder

1. create an SPD2010 workflow and use the Update Item action to change the path and name of the document.
2. After inserting the update list item action click on the `"this list"` link and set the  dropdown to `Current Item`.
3. Then click Add, select the `"Path and Name"` field click on the `"..."`, type in your folder name followed by a `/`,
4. then click `"Add or Change Lookup"`, select `Current Item` as the data source and the field as Name.
5. The stringbilder should then show `yourfoldername/[%Current Item:Name]` (where `yourfoldername` is relevant to the library root). Click OK and publish the workflow in the normal way.
6. When you run the workflow it will move the doc to the specified folder.

Many thanks to [Move items into a SharePoint list folder](http://mylittlesharepoint.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/move-items-into-folder.html) for this solution.

Comment: can this be used to move documents between two different libraries?!?!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why there is so much confusion about how to implement a custom workflow action (I'm confused as well).  I found numerous guides on how to do this and they all required deployment to the GAC and registering smart controls in the Web.Config.  I couldn't get this to work.  Then I found a blog with steps on how to implement a custom action in a sandboxed solution (preferable for me anyway) and it was easy peasy.  I created a workflow that takes an input parameter for the folder path from the workflow designer and moves the item to the folder.  This thread is old, but I just want everyone to know this is super easy as a sandboxed solution. I used the below guide and just added my logic for moving to a folder.  I recommend creating a list receiver that moves the items to a folder first because troubleshooting a list receiver is a thousand times easier than troubleshooting a workflow.  So, validate your code in a list receiver then add it to the workflow based on the guide below.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798499.aspx

Comment: For me, if it involves creating an event receiver, it's no good. Because our farm/system is so closed down to external input, I cannot even add SP templates for Visual Studio onto our system, which is needed in order to create the event receiver in the first place. Ugly, ugly, ugly. Thanks for your input, as I believe it will help others in the future. Something you may want to do is actually input the steps here (duplicate your entry), so the information is not lost through a link change or something unforseen in the future.

Comment: yes, I created an list receiver first, but a workflow action is more flexible as the conditions and parameters can be changed with recompiling and redeploying your solution. Again, this was done in a sandbox solution. It doesn't require deploying to the GAC.  If you can deploy a list receiver, you should be able to deploy this custom action to the sandbox as well.