# Uploading document to folder automatically

Tags: document-library, tagging

If I upload a document with a specific tag is it possible for it to be placed in a specific folder within the doc library without me having to place it there? I'm new to SharePoint so sorry if this is a dumb question. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the following options: [Content Organizer](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-Content-Organizer-rules-to-route-documents-1e4d37a3-635d-4764-b0fc-f7c5356c1900?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) (and Drop Off library) and SharePoint Workflow (for example, refer to [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/71482/sp2010-use-workflow-to-move-library-item-into-folder) post for a start.

Each option provides ability to extract document properties and route the documents directly without user interaction to specified paths (folders, libraries).